# C++ - Printing numbers in a circular pattern using nested for loops

Tags: c++, loops, nested

I've gotten myself into a bit of a problem here. I'm supposed to print a circular clock like figure but I just can't seem to get it right.

This is kind of what the clock should look like, in my own mental draft:

```
       12
   11      01
 10          02
09            03
 08          04
   07      05
       06

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () { 

    int i, j, space = 4, number1 = 11;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < space; j++)
            cout << " ";

        for (number1; number1 > 6; number1--)   
            cout << number1 << "\n";    

    }

}
```

Now, what I've written is not even close to what I need over here, and I would really appreciate it if you guys could give me a few hints and tips regarding this problem. I've only been coding for a few weeks now, by the way.

Comment: I bet this could be done in a single for loop, row by row. The trick is to find a pattern between the number of spaces needed before each number and the corresponding line it's on (Index of the loop).

Comment: i would not compute the numbers on the fly, but make a table of what numbers go in which row, then when printing you only need to care about the formatting

Comment: @tobi303 Would you suggest I put the numbers in an array and print them through a  loop? That might work so I'm gonna go give it a try.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't even use loops to build this dynamically. I'd just shove the output you want into a literal string and write that.

Comment: @cdhowie Yeah, that would be the most sensible route to take but it's a part of an assignment. I've completed the rest but I just can't seem to make this one particular program work.

Comment: It's a shame youngsters aren't taught the old tricks anymore: an elegant solution drops out if you research "how to draw a circle without using trig functions". This is how we used to draw circles quickly in machine code in the 1980s. Nice question by the way.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you for the kind words, and I absolutely share your views.

I also figured it out so the admins can archive this thread :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () { 

    int i, j, space = 5,space2=0, number1 = 12;

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < space; j++)
            cout << " ";

            cout<<number1;

            if(i!=0&&i!=6)
            {
                for(j=0;j<space2;j++)
                cout<<" ";

                cout<<12-number1;
            }

            number1--;
            cout<<endl;

            if(i<3)
            space-=2,space2+=3;
            else
            space+=2,space2-=3;
            }
}
```